# Remove line if list of bad words are found

Tags: python, python-3.x

Remove a line if an undesired word is found in the sentence. The bad words are cat and dog.
Given a text file:

```
orange
cat is bad
dog is bad
water
egg
```

I would like it to look like:

```
orange
water
egg
```

Here is my code so far. I am not sure why this still returns a text file with the sentences that include the bad words. :

```
bad_words=[cat, dog]
with open('some.txt','r') as f:
   lines=f.readlines()

with open('some.txt','w') as f:
for i in lines:
   if  not any(bad_word in i for bad_word in bad_words):
      f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: You want to write `i`, not `lines`, right now you're simply writing all lines to the file every time a word gets past the check

Comment: what is `lines` . what is `f` ?

Comment: Sorry lines was what readlines() was loaded into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change f.writelines(lines) to f.writelines(i)